# How to print non matching words from seperate text files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

For my project, I would like to learn how to Print Non-Matching words from two separate text files, and print the non-matching terms onto a Separate third text file. Currently, I have two separate text files, like this.

----------File1------

```
    What is 2+2?  A = 1, B* = 4, C = 10, D = 12, E = 14
    What is a 7+7?  A = 144, B* = 14, C* = 32, D = 95, E = 16
    What is 1x1?  A* = 1, B = 7, C = 21, D = 420, E = 1762
    What is 10/2?  A = 4, B = 10, C = 2, D* = 5, E = 210
    What is 4^2?  A = 10, B = 20, C = 1, D* = 16, E = 980
    What is 5+1?  A = 4, B = 1, C = 0, D = 2, E* = 6
    What is 5x0?  A = 8, B = 10, C* = 0, D = 2, E = 20
    What is 9+10?  A* = 19, B = 7, C = 8, D = 221, E = 21
    What is 2+1?  A = 2, B* = 3, C = 9, D = 12, E = 32
    What is 6+6+6?  A = 19, B = 27, C* = 18, D = 12, E = 234
```

----------File2-------

```
    A*
    B*
    C*
    D* 
    E*
    A*
    D*
    E*
    B*
    E*
```

Both of these files have there characters printed on separate lines. I would like to know how to match the two files, and print the Non matching words on separate lines. For example, on line 1, the word A* is  not matching in either text file , so it would be printed onto a separate third text file.

My attempt

```
f1 = open("QuestionsMaths.txt", "r")
f2 = open("AnswersMaths.txt", "r")
f3 = open("Feedback.txt", "a")
list1 = f1.readlines()
list2 = f2.readlines()
f3.write("The incorrect answers are: \n")
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i==j:
            f3.write(i)
```

Yet all this code does is print the sentence *The incorrect answers are:*

Very new to Python, so any instructional detail on code, will be much appreciated. Hope I'm Clear. Thanks.

Comment: What should be the output like?

Comment: @VinilNarang the output should be just in the same way File2 is presented, so just each non-matching word printed on a separate line.

Comment: Can you please give a sample output for the above case?

Comment: The output for File3 would be like: If word A* wasn't matching, 'A*' on line 1, if B* also wasn't matching , 'B*' on line 2

Comment: Okay. I am still not clear on the output format. But maybe what you are doing wrong here is that, you are comparing two complete lines. What you should be really doing is checking if line2 is contained in line1. You can use different string functions "issubstr" or "contains" to check this. Hope it helps!

Comment: @VinilNarang thanks for the response.The output for the third file was just meant to be like this . http://puu.sh/jh9vg/32a5ae5796.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program should look like this:

```
with open("QuestionsMaths.txt", "r") as f1:
    list1 = f1.readlines()
with open("AnswersMaths.txt", "r") as f2:
    list2 = f2.readlines()

with open("Feedback.txt", "a") as f3:
    f3.write("The incorrect answers are: \n")

    for questionLine, answerLine in zip(list1, list2):
        if answerLine.strip() not in questionLine:
            f3.write(answerLine)
```

Explanation
`with open(filename, ...) as f` is the proper way to use a file. If you do it like this it will be automatically closed when there is an exception or the indented block is finished. Note that `f` is only usable within this block. [See last paragraph here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

`answerLine.strip()` will remove line end and other whitespaces. We need to do this because in `questionLine` the right answer will never be followed by a line end but in `answerLine` it certainly will. [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

`zip(list1, list2)` will give you pairs of lines so that you match the first line of `list1` with the first line of `list2` and so on. With your implementation you were actually matching all lines from `list1` with all lines from `list2`. [zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip)

`if answerLine not in questionLine` will check wheter `answerLine` does NOT occur in `questionLine`. If you use `answerLine == questionLine` you will check whether the strings are the SAME. [See Note here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Finally a slight remark. If all what you put into your third file are the wrong answers, you cannot match them to the actual questions they came from.
Therefore I'd suggest to improve the for-loop again like this:

```
for question, (questionLine, answerLine) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2), 1):
    if answerLine.strip() not in questionLine:
        # answerLine still ends with lineend, so no lineend in
        # the format string.
        f3.write('Q{}: {}'.format(question, answerLine))
```

`enumerate(iterable, start=0)` will return a tuple containing the index together with the corresponding element of a list (which in this case is again a tuple). Yes, python can resolve nested tuples like this.
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate)

"Feedback.txt" with the improved for-loop and your example as input:

```
The incorrect answers are:
Q1: A*
Q3: C*
Q5: E*
Q6: A*
Q7: D*
Q8: E*
Q10: E*
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, the code works perfectly, but most of all, you wrote a detailed explanation of all the functions. You also wrote a remark which I didn't even think of. Thank you so much, and Brilliant Work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists with the same length, you can enumerate one list and compare it to the other. With map and enumerate it is a oneliner. After that you have a list with all the results:

```py
list3 = map(lambda (i,x): x if x in list1[i] else '', enumerate(list2))
print '\n'.join(list3)
```

Just save it into your third file.

I recommend to first strip the items in the two lists to avoid matching problems:

```py
list1 = map(lambda r: r.strip(), list1)
list2 = map(lambda r: r.strip(), list2)
```